# Submit button CSS not listening?

Tags: html, css, input, submit

I am creating an e-mail form and would like the text box and submit button to be directly next to each other. They should be touching so that it looks like one continuous rectangle.

However, when I get them touching and set a height the submit button doesn't listen! It doesn't stay the same height. If I increase the submit button height alone by a lot the two boxes are not aligned!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="form">
    <input type="text" class="text-input" name="address" id="address" value="" size="23" maxlegnth="30" />
    <input type="submit" value="BUTTON" id="btn-submit" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#form input{
    border: solid 2px #989898;
    font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    outline:none;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #525252;
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
}
#address{
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 30 0 auto;
}
#btn-submit{
    margin-left: -7px;
    width: 44px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to `float:left` the inputs and then set a height for them. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/NweS6/

```
#form input{
    border: solid 2px #989898;
    font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    outline: none;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    color: #525252;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
}

#form #btn-submit{
    margin-left: -2px;
    width: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 29px;
}
```

The reason the submit needs a figure 4px higher than the input is because for some reason it does not take into the account the border on the button, which top and bottom adds up to 4px.

Comment: @dasaki: Can you please let me know if this helped? Or could you tell me what solution you did use, if not this one?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you write an HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action"/page/to_post_to" >
    <input type="text" class="text-input" name="address" id="address" value="" size="23" maxlegnth="30" />
    <input type="submit" value="BUTTON" id="btn-submit" />
</form>
```

Then the elements inside it know it is a `form`, not just another `div`.

**EDIT**: Sorry I misread your question. I thought listening meant it was behaving wrong instead of displaying wrong.

Did you want it to look like the followin? http://jsfiddle.net/4HcWy/6/

```
form input
{
    border:2px solid #989898;
    font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    outline:none;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #525252;
    position:relative;
    height: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#address{
    text-align:right;
    margin:0 30 0 auto;
    border-right: none;
}
#btn-submit{
    margin-left: -7px;
    width:44px;
    text-align:center;
    border-left: none;
}
```

(Also, since I had used a `form` element I had to change `#form input` to `form input`.)*

Comment: changing the div to form made no difference :/

Comment: You have to have a form elelment or it doesn't matter. You need to specify an `action=` (i made a typo) and it has to point to the correct page that you need it to. (Oops! didn't read your question properly).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 2 pixels can't work on the input and button but with 1 pixel borders, it's OK.

Look: http://jsfiddle.net/qwLV7/

**Update**

This seems to work, but I had to hack the height of the button to be higher than the input,

http://jsfiddle.net/qwLV7/1/

**Update 2**

How's that now?

http://jsfiddle.net/qwLV7/2/

CSS

```
#form1
{
    border:solid 2px #989898;
    font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    background: #d8d8d8;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #525252;
    position:relative;
    width:194px;
}

input{
  height:25px;
  border:0px;
}

#address{
    text-align:right;
    margin:0 30 0 auto;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
}

#btn-submit{
    width:44px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="form1">
    <input type="text" class="text-input" name="address" id="address" value="" size="23" maxlegnth="30" />
    <input type="submit" value="BUTTON" id="btn-submit" />
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I did try adjusting heights though and I'm just trying to find a solution that doesn't require me to do that... It's quite weird!

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I just increased the size of the text and left the heights alone

Comment: If it helped you to find the anwser, in Stackoverflow we love Votes, so it could be kind of you if you could vote for my answer and if it was a good solution "green check" my answer. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Float the submit button and the layout will look as expected. 
http://jsfiddle.net/4HcWy/9/