# How can I prevent a <button> shrinking to the size of it's content?

Tags: html, css

I have two elements in a container:

```
<div class="container">
    <span>This is a div</span>
    <button>This is a button</button>
</div>
```

Styled as follows:

```
span, button {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    font: inherit;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can see a live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/925qz/).

Why does the button not appear the same width as the span? How can I make the button behave like a standard block-level element?

I need to use a `<button>` here because its purpose is to submit the form.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: Not if I apply `display: block` to the button, it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm expecting there to be some ruleset that makes them both
>   behave like `<div>`s

There isn't. The reason is that `button` is a ["replaced element"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element).

The clearest source I could find on this was: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements

> A replaced element is any element whose appearance and dimensions are
>   defined by an external resource. Examples include images (`<img>` tags),
>   plugins (`<object>` tags), and form elements (`<button>`, `<textarea>`,
>   `<input>`, and `<select>` tags). All other elements types can be referred
>   to as non-replaced elements.
>
> Replaced elements can also have visual formatting requirements imposed
>   by the element, outside of the control of CSS; for example, the user
>   interface controls rendered for form elements.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/925qz/18/

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
span, button {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    font: inherit;
}
button{
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: If he can set `padding` on `.container`, you have the best answer by far.

Comment: While I agree this fixes the problem, I'm more concerned about what style I need to override to make it behave like a span. Particularly in webkit, since everything seems to boil down to vendor-specific css.

Comment: @eric: I don't understand what you are looking for: "what style I need to override to make it behave like a span". Are you expecting there to be one rule that will make it the same as a `span`?

Comment: @tw16: I'm expecting there to be some ruleset that makes them both behave like `<div>`s

Comment: @eric: There isn't. The issue is similar to a question I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810418/submit-button-css-not-listening/6810693#6810693). The `button` element does not conform with the standard box model. So padding and borders need to be taken into account.

Comment: @tw16: I can fix the box model problem with `box-sizing: content-box`. The only remaining problem is the shrink-wrapping behaviour.

Comment: @eric: The reason I avoided mentioning `box-sizing: content-box` is because the implementation is slightly different among different browsers and does not work totally as expected. I was just about to post an example of this, but I had a brainwave as I was typing. There was extra padding being applied to the button even when none was declared and *normalized css* did not reset this. So I have now explicitly removed side padding from my answer and set *both* to `width:100%` and used `box-sizing`. Do you prefer this instead? http://jsfiddle.net/925qz/37/

Answer (score 1):

Separate the span and button selectors, then add width to the button selector.

Comment: +1 although I don't think you necessarily need to separate the existing ones.  However you do need another selector just for the button with a width attribute.

Comment: What width would I give it? They're supposed to fill up the container, whatever size it is, leaving 5px on either side.

Comment: @Eric: I just tried your code, 97% seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @techsilo: NO NO NO NO NO! Don't mix pixel and percentage widths and expect them to add to 100%!

Comment: @Eric: If you want to use fixed width, I guess you need to specify width for the .container as well (or you at least need to guess the default width of the .container wherever you are doing to use this).

Answer (score 0):

Browsers often ship with divergent default styles for many elements. Header elements such as h1 and h2, ul, strong and em all are styled with default CSS. A general tactic is to use something like the [Yahoo! reset css stylesheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) to remove these styles for better cross-browser appearance.

This would not immediately help with your button problem, but partly explains it. Internally, complex elements within browsers such as the button are defined by HTML that you don't have access to as a user. This internal HTML is also styled via CSS. In the case of a button you'll have to use explicit CSS to style it in ways other than the browser has been instructed to. Give it a `width` and understand that internal padding rules may give it divergent appearance from a div or span with similar rules.

Answer (score 0):

Form elements use a different box-model in pretty much every browser. That’s why they never actually have the same size as the other elements, even if all have the same dimensions set. I also found a bug report from Firefox for this problem: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=562153

I always put the following code in my reset stylesheet to have a more even working ground:

```
select, input, textarea, button {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The code works from IE8 and up and all other major browsers, according to PPK: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a width of 100% (like block elements usually have) to the button it will ignore the padding! I had this problem a few days ago:

[<button> padding / width problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790512/button-padding-width-problem)

If u want to fill out all of the width and apply padding, this should do the job:

```
button {
    width: 100%; 
    /* prefixes for box-sizing here */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Of course the total width will be 100% + the padding, so it'll be more than you want. You may have to take a fix width, because of that.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/925qz/30/

How I corrected it:
The padding for left and right is set but the all around its managed by the container
The width is 100% for the button.
Lastly the button's separation is managed by top 5px margin.

```
span, button {
    display: block;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    font: inherit;
}

button{
    margin-top:5px;
    width:100%;  
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
}
```